# getLastKnownLocation(getProviderName()) is null in Jellybean

Tags: android, gps

i made TrackerGps but i got some problem when checking gps. in Device Lollipop my gps is work, but when i trying to Device Jellybean my gps not work, always get null and already set permission location in setting app

```
  public Location getLocation() {
//        provider = getProviderName();
        //set provider
        setProvider(provider);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // getting GPS status
        boolean statusProvider = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (statusProvider) {
                //set can get location
                setCanGetLocation(true);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, ValueConfig.MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, ValueConfig.MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getProviderName());
                    if (location != null) {
                        setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                        setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
                        setAccuracy(location.getAccuracy());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Shorcut.turnGPSOn(context);
            }
        } else {
            Shorcut.turnGPSOn(context);
        }

        return location;
    }
```

and my app, when open will show top up checking permission in device lollipop

Answer (score 0):

Once check the app permissions in your settings. I recommend you to use Google fused location provider to get location. Because it gives best and accurate results.